# Why is this comparison always true?

Tags: c++, warnings, unsigned-char

I have the following code in my file:

```
unsigned char * pData = new unsigned char...

...

if(pData[0] >= 160 && pData[0] <= 255)
```

When I compile it, I get a warning from the compiler (gcc):

> **Warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type**

How can this be? Isn't the range of an `unsigned char` 0-255? I'm confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the range of `unsigned char` is from `0` to `255` and `pData[0]` is a `char` then `pData[0] <= 255` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `pData[0] <= 255` is always true since the range of `unsigned char` is 0..255 (in your particular implementation).

It's only complaining about that bit of the expressions since `pData[0] >= 160` can be true *or* false.

Keep in mind that the range of an `unsigned char` need not be 0..255 for *all* implementations (ISO C standards do not mandate this).

Answer (score 3):

The second part of the comparison is redundant.  It is always less than or equal to 255.

Comment: *[facepalm]* Why didn't I see that?

Comment: Assuming `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `char` is unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

You should always parenthasise your expressions to avoid ambiguity, such as:

```
if ((pData[0] >= 160) && (pData[0] <= 255))
```

Does this solve the problem?

The second comparison is redundant, so use:

```
if (pData[0] >= 160)
```

Comment: Operator precedence has nothing to do with this... the relational operators have higher precedence than the binary logical operators.

Comment: No, there is no ambiguity. Operator precedence does what I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the range of an unsigned char
>   0-255?

The range of unsigned char is implementation defined (in contrast to some of the other posts). This is because the number of bits used to represent a char is not 8 always. It is just that a char takes 1 8bit location on your particular implementation and hence 255 is the upper limit.

So in case there is a some other meaning attached to 255 (other than `'numeric_limits<char>::max()`'), I think you should still go ahead and use the check, else the check is redundant.